# Regexp matching with custom validation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to create a custom validation method but getting an error

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..3)
```

I want to validate the format of a postcode but provide a custom error message as opposed to the message i get if i was to do this

```
validates_format_of :postcode, with: /\A^(GIR 0AA|[A-PR-UWYZ]([0-9]{1,2}|([A-HK-Y][0-9]|[A-HK-Y][0-9]([0-9]|[ABEHMNPRV-Y]))|[0-9][A-HJKS-UW])[ ]{0,1}[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$\z/i, message: 'Please check your postcode'
```

This will give an error message of

```
postcode Please check your postcode
```

So i though i could do this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
validate :format_postcode

 def format_postcode
  regexp = /\A^(GIR 0AA|[A-PR-UWYZ]([0-9]{1,2}|([A-HK-Y][0-9]|[A-HK-Y][0-9]([0-9]|[ABEHMNPRV-Y]))|[0-9][A-HJKS-UW])[ ]{0,1}[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$\z/i
   if !postcode.match(regexp)
     errors.add[:base] << "Please check your Postcode"
   end
 end
end
```

But this is throwing the error

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line

```
errors.add[:base] << "Please check your Postcode"
```

it should be

```
errors.add :base, "Please check your Postcode"
```

As the error message suggests, `add` is a method that takes 1..3 arguments, not a getter for an array.

Comment: thanks, silly error there really... thanks for pointing that out, i ended up using errors[:base] << "Please check your Postcode"